# Преобразование массива php, изменение вложенности

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Название  
            [1] =>  Время              
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => раз
            [1] => два
        )

    )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => три 
            [1] => четыре
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Название2 
            [1] => Время
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => пять 
            [1] => шесть
        )

    )
```

Нужно преобразовать его вот так:

```
Array
(
  [Название] => Array 
                       (
                       [0] =>  раз
                       [1] =>  два
                       )        


  [Название] => Array
                       (
                       [0] =>  три
                       [1] =>  четыре
                       )  
  [Название2] => Array
                       (
                       [0] =>  пять
                       [1] =>  шесть
                       ) 
 )
```

Суть в том, что массив содержит произвольный набор вложенных массивов второго уровня, часть которых являются заголовком для последующих. Схематично:

> Название; Поле; Поле; Поле; Название2; Поле; Поле;

Мне нужно все последующие поля за названием привязать к этому названию, следующие так же. Количество элементов одинаковое, количество массивов всегда разное.
Любые идеи?

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос так:
Из массива с названием взял название

```
if((strpos($str[0], 'Название') != false))
```

и добавил в качестве элемента к каждому последующему массиву, текущий массив удалил.

```
$_SESSION['name_var'] = $str[0];
unset($str);
```

При изменении названия меняю переменную и присваиваю новое значение. Костыль и фекалокод, возможно есть более изящный способ?